# How to convert text from recipenameiput to json

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I am making recipe page(just for learning), and i need to convert recipenameinput to a json, but i dont now how, script just gives this - ['{}']. how do i convert this?

```
function submitrecipe(form) {
    var recipenameinput, recipeinput, submit;
    recipenameinput = document.getElementById('recipename');
    recipeinput = document.getElementById('recipe');
  submit = document.getElementById('submit');

  const values = [];
  
  
  values.push(JSON.stringify(recipenameinput));
  console.log(values);
  

  }
```

```
<div class="submit">
    <h1>Submit a recipe</h1>
    <!--recipe form-->
    <div class="form">
    <form method="post">
        <label for="recipename">Write your recipe name</h2>
            <br>
        <input type="text" id="recipename">
        <br>
        <label for="recipe">write your recipe</h2>
            <br>
        <input type="text" id="recipe">
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" for="submit" onclick="submitrecipe()">
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What value did you expect when you tried to convert an HTMLInputElement object to JSON? Do you really want to convert the HTMLInputElement object itself?

Comment: My guess is that you want to push recipenameinput.value, which is the string that the user entered into the input. recipenameinput itself is an HTML DOM Element, which is being represented as a JavaScript object when you convert it to JSON.